# Synonym request for emulation: emulators

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

The recent question about [Genesis emulation/all emulators](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/24699/8366) seems to have led to a [follow-up question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/24714/8366) that's tagged with both [emulation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emulation) and [emulators](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emulators); only three questions are tagged with the latter, and in two cases, [emulation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emulation) is already there.

We already have [emulator](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emulator) as a synonym ... seems to me like [emulators](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emulators) should join it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This makes sense and has been done.